# Advice for replacing img tags with text in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to work out how to store an html table of drive stats in a database, but the developers have been a bit clever, and started using gifs to represent pass/fail/health stats

Here's a snippet of what I've got:

```
<tr class="status">
<td class="status"><img border="0" src="/tick_green.gif"></td>
<td class="status">8</td>
<td class="status">Ready</td>
<td class="status"><a href="/cgi-bin/status_drive?cont=0&amp;dylan=0&amp;drive=8"><img border="0" src="/bar10.gif"></a></td>
<td class="status">SEAGATE ST3146807FC</td>
<td class="status">10000 RPM</td>
<td class="status">3HY61AG9</td>
<td class="status">XR12</td>
<td class="status">286749488</td>
<td class="status"> 28.0&#176;C</td>
<td class="status" style="background-color: #00fa00">&#160;
</td>
```

**

And here's some of the ruby that I've written so far to strip the tags:

```
table = page.parser.xpath('//table/caption[contains(.,"Drive")]/..')
table.xpath('//table//tr').each do |row|
  row.xpath('td').each do |cell|
    puts   cell.to_html.gsub(/<a[^>]+>/,'').gsub(/<td[^>]+>/,'').gsub(/<\/td[^>]*>/,'').gsub(/<\/a[^>]*>/,'')
    #puts cell.text
  end
end
```

I can now get semi-rational output

```
<img border="0" src="/tick_green.gif">
15
Ready
<img border="0" src="/bar10.gif">
SEAGATE ST3146807FC
10000 RPM
3HY61ASW
XR12
286749488
 29.0&#176;C
&#160;
```

But I want to replace a couple of other cell elements with other bits
For example, the tick_green can also be '/cross_red.gif' or '/caution.gif' which I want to replace with regular text, likewise, the img bar10.gif, I want to replace with just text of '10'
Is it best to come up with a whole bunch of values for all of my special cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A case statement will clean that up a little but:

```
row.css('td').each do |td|
    img = td.at('img')
    puts case
        when img && img[:src][/bar(\d+)\.gif/] then $1
        when img && img[:src][/tick_green/] then 'ok'
        else td.text.strip
    end
end
```

Comment: Cool - thank you... ran out of time to test this today, but will have a go in the morning

Comment: That seems to work pretty well - I'm going to try and poke it into a database later

Comment: Ended up using 2d array
       clean_table = []
       table.css('tr').each do |tr|
        clean_row = []
         tr.css('td').each do |td|
          img = td.at('img')
          clean_row.push case
          when img && img[:src][/bar(\d+)\.gif/] then 'Health: '+$1
          when img && img[:src][/tick_green/] then 'Healthy'
          when img && img[:src][/cross_red/] then 'Failed'
          when img && img[:src][/caution/] then 'Caution'
          else td.text.strip
          end
        end
      clean_table.push clean_row
      end
    clean_table.each {|x|
      puts "#{x}"
    }

Answer (score 1):

I'd do some 'gsub'iing.

E.g.:

```
example = <<-STRING
<img border="0" src="/tick_green.gif">
15
Ready
<img border="0" src="/bar10.gif">
SEAGATE ST3146807FC
10000 RPM
3HY61ASW
XR12
286749488
29.0&#176;C
&#160;
STRING

replace = Hash.new("#unknown")
replace['tick_green.gif'] = "[OK]"
replace['bar10.gif'] = "[10]"

regex = /<img [^>]* src="\/(.*)">/
result = example.gsub(regex) { replace[$1] }
```

Somehow the I'd like to replace the $1 with a named backreference, but don't know how yet.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-gsub

edit: result from above

```
[OK]
15
Ready
[10]
SEAGATE ST3146807FC
10000 RPM
3HY61ASW
XR12
286749488
 29.0&#176;C
&#160;
```

Comment: Cool - thanks for that Deradon... much appreciated - I'll post back when I've had a chance to put it together in a script

Comment: You're using regex to parse html which is bad, especially since nokogiri has already parsed it for you.